# Why can't I access my var outside a function

Tags: jquery

Why can't I call `cursorImg` outside? I tried to call it in a `return` and a `console.log` but I get `undefined`

```js
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  var cursorImg;
    function returnData(cursorImg) {
      return [
        cursorImg,
        myJson_departement_list[i]["dep_name"],
        "<br/>",
        myJson_departement_list[i]["total_parrainages"],
        " parrainages",
        "</strong></div>",
      ].join("");
    }
    
  $("#map-france").on("click", function (e, returnData) {
    var x = e.pageX - $("#map-france").offset().left;

    cursorImg =
      x > $("#map-france").width() / 2
        ? '<div class="hoverinfo" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: -35px;"><strong>'
        : '<div class="hoverinfo" style="position: absolute; left: 2rem; bottom: -35px;"><strong>';
        console.log("test ", cursorImg); // test undefined 
  });
}
```

```css
#map-france {
  width: 50rem;
  height: 50rem;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-france"> </div>
```

This `return` returns just the name of the department:

```
(`myJson_departement_list[i]["dep_name"]` + total (`myJson_departement_list[i]["total_parrainages"]`) + " parrainages"
```

Comment: At the time `console.log("test " , cursorImg)` get executed, `cursorImg` has not been initialized or filled with any data.

Comment: `cursorImg` is only set after the `mousemove` event has occurred. You cannot `return` anything from an event handler

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, but `cursorImg` was already initialized above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't get it :(

Comment: it's normal behavior you console the var before initializing  on mousemove try to console your var inside  mousemove  event

Comment: What do you think `$("#map-france").on("mousemove",` does?

Comment: If you move your console.log to the second line (directly under the `var` statement) - would you expect it to be defined?

Comment: i updated my post, i can see the consolelog now, but notting in the `$("#map-france").text(" cursorImg : ", cursorImg);`

Comment: i can't see how can i call the var `cursorImg` in the return statment i commented ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, so how can i get the cursorImg value in the return[] ?

Comment: Using the pattern in the question, it will be set, but only after the `click` event has run. Think about how the logic flows. Your code instantiates the variable with no value, then immediately tries to use it, so it has no value. As some random point in the future the event handler will run and set the value, but at that point you're not doing anything with the value.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cursorImg; // You are defining a new variable here.

$("#map-france").on("click", function(e) {
  // ...
  cursorImg = /*...*/ // You are setting the value of the variable here.
});

return [ cursorImg, /*..*/ ] // You are returning here.
```

Lets think about this scenario from the point of view of the Javascript interpreter.

It's going to run your code from top to bottom:

1. Define a new variable called `cursorImg`.
2. When the `#map-france` element is clicked, run this function which sets the value of `cursorImg` **but not until a click event happens**.
3. Return an array which contains `cursorImg` and a few other things.

When the interpreter gets to number 3 (i.e, your return statement), the function inside the `click` event hasn't been run yet, and the value of `cursorImg` is still `undefined`.

The value of `cursorImg` will only get set when the function inside the click event is executed, i.e. when you click on the `#map-france` element, but here's the important part: **the interpreter won't wait at step 2 for that to happen**, as the click event is **asynchronous**.

This is where you need to understand the concept of a callback. [Here's the relevant MSDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), and a [good tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-callback/) which might help you understand.

Comment: Thank you for your post @James, it's a bit advanced for me, i just want to know for the moment, why cursorImg is empty when i call it in the `return[]` because i can't move it in the click function :( i have nothing in the fonrt if i do so

Comment: @winweb I've told you why. The function run by the click event doesn't run until a click event occurs. You cannot return a value set by an asynchronous callback function in the parent function, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @winweb Your function just isn't going to work in the way you are expecting. You'll need to read the tutorial I've given you and refactor your code.

Comment: i updated my post, but i have a warning in `$("#map-france").on("click", function (e, returnData) {` >>  'returnData' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133